# Protractor: How to check if the table/grid is populated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I wanted to check if my table/grid is populated using Protractor. I believe I can do this with something like:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('someRepeate')).count()).toBe(somecount);
```

But the problem is I don't know the exact count as it is dynamically populated. Anyone has any idea how could I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can check that the *count is more than `0`*:

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('someRepeater')).count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Guess I need to learn Protractor more. :-)